# Strange mesa package version for some ubuntu-22.04 installations - 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2

Tags: package-management

We use ubuntu-22.04 on many of our desktops. Only the official repos are configured for them, they do daily updates. For some of our desktops, the packages

- libegl-mesa0
- libgbm1
- libgl1-mesa-dri
- libglapi-mesa
- libglx-mesa0
- libxatracker2
- mesa-va-drivers
- mesa-vdpau-drivers
- mesa-vulkan-drivers

got updated to a version that isn't available any more. For example for libgbm1, on the affected system I get this:

```
myself@dell-xps:~$ apt policy libgbm1
libgbm1:
  Installed: 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2
  Candidate: 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

On systems that have been offline end of May, the output looks like this:

```
uli@cslpc06:~/git/java-einlern-projekt$ apt policy libgbm1
libgbm1:
  Installiert:           22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1
  Installationskandidat: 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

From my point of view, some systems do have a version of the packages which isn't available for update any more.

How shall I cleanup the situation? I have a "bad feeling" running systems with "strange packages".

Thanks for looking into this and best regards, Uli

Comment: If the *outdated* packages are "*strange*" to you, then apply all upgrades and bring your systems back into being *updated*. The packages are still there, but being *outdated* they get *dropped* from the software lists which very much concentrate on the *latest* packages for *security* reasons.

Comment: It looks like newer packages are available [22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/libgbm1), and older ones are removed, because why keep them. Nothing strange about it. You can run `apt-get changelog libgbm1` to see all previous versions.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time looking into this. It seems the issue has been resolved roughly around 20th of June by publishing 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3 as mentioned by the comments above. I missed to check this before asking, sorry.